# JQ sort integer values in JSON

Tags: json, jq

I have a bunch of JSON objects as:

```
{"AccountID":"290859614811","number_of_requests":"59944"}
{"AccountID":"421258792169","number_of_requests":"3132"}
{"AccountID":"433594311540","number_of_requests":"1541"}
{"AccountID":"406912498377","number_of_requests":"678"}
{"AccountID":"850981987534","number_of_requests":"558"}
{"AccountID":"763725063017","number_of_requests":"470"}
{"AccountID":"notaccount","number_of_requests":"8"}
....
```

I am trying to sort them in ascending order based on the number_of_requests.

but when I run the following:

`jq -S '.results[] | map( { (.field) : .value} ) | add ' FILENAME | jq -s -c 'sort_by(.number_of_requests)[]'`

I end up with:

```
{"AccountID":"433594311540","number_of_requests":"1541"}
{"AccountID":"421258792169","number_of_requests":"3132"}
{"AccountID":"763725063017","number_of_requests":"470"}
{"AccountID":"850981987534","number_of_requests":"558"}
{"AccountID":"290859614811","number_of_requests":"59944"}
{"AccountID":"406912498377","number_of_requests":"678"}
{"AccountID":"notaccount","number_of_requests":"8"}
...
```

Basically, the sort_by function treats "558"/"59944" as lesser than "8" , "6" etc. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the value to a number, with `tonumber`:

```
jq -s -c 'sort_by(.number_of_requests|tonumber)'
```